Updating Jira tickets from Jenkins workflow
In our pipeline library we have below code to update jiras
try {
        step([$class       : 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater',
              issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.DefaultIssueSelector'],
              scm          : scm
        ])

so by using this, it is updating all the jira's. eg., If someone committed as below:
REL-12345: CAL-56789 this is testing
so for above commit it will update comment on both Jira's instead of updating first Jira only
How can I update only first jira?

Try specifying the issue explicitly with ExplicitIssueSelector instead of 'DefaultIssueSelector'.

Thanks for answering, ExplicitIssueSelector will only update first Jira ticket of every commit instead of all Jira's which are there in single commit?
